# With different versions of skates, is it worth getting a better one for an extra 20 dollars?

Tags: ice-hockey

When I go and buy skates, lets say *Bauer supreme* there are usually different versions like *Bauer supreme*140 or Bauer supreme 150, 160 etc. The man helping me with my skates said that each one is a little better but is it really worth the extra 20 dollars to get a 140 over a 150? Can someone just tell me the main differences so I can figure out what which version to buy?

Comment: We can't answer this question for you - we don't know how significant $20 is to you, and we don't know if a little more performance will make a big difference to whatever you're trying to do on the skates.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that what I needed was something highlighting the main differences.

Comment: Sorry, but [shopping questions aren't something we do either](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Did you consider just asking the guy in the store?

Comment: I think you could salvage this question by asking something along the lines of "In general, what features make a skate better as the model numbers increase?"

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a [shopping recommendation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an exhaustive list and I'm not an expert, but, *in general*:

- lower priced models often can't be baked--so will take longer to wear in.
- lower priced models have non-replaceable blades, higher priced models can be replaced
- the more expensive the model, typically the lighter the overall skate due to lighter weight materials
- the more expensive the model, the higher quality materials

We can't tell you which model is right for you. It all depends on your personal preferences, your budget and how much you play.